# rails console mode app.get uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I am running rails 4.1.8 and encountered this error in console mode

`RAILS_ENV=production rails c`

`irb(main):001:0> app.get "/main/abcgenerator"` abcgenerator is a method in my maincontroller

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant MainController::AbcgeneratorDef):
app/controllers/main_controller.rb:40:in <class:MainController>'
app/controllers/main_controller.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
```

I have AbcgeneratorDef.rb under app/controllers/concerns/
and already included it in main controller like this

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
    require 'AbcgeneratorDef';
    include AbcgeneratorDef;
```

The /main/abcgenerator link works perfectly in browser (i.e. If I run `rails s`, and paste the link into browser. It won't complain any thing)

It just fails in console mode

I tried to add this to config/application.rb

`config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/concerns"`

it worked last week, but this week it strangely failed to work anymore

Comment: Things become even more strange now. When I change the `config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/concerns"` to `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/concerns)` it works in console mode.

Comment: even I comment out the config.autoload_paths xxxxxx. it still works in console mode

Comment: it seems like I just need to "touch" the config/application.rb in order to make it work. I was totally confused

Comment: I think this is because you are not using Rails convention of naming files. According to conventions, your file name should be `abcgenerator_def.rb` for the class name `AbcgeneratorDef` . You need not add any other code or directories to autoload_paths, just set it to default configuration. This is because rails require all the files recursively for any directory which is included in its default autoload_paths and controllers directory is already there by default. So all the folders and files inside it will be required and initialized while application loading.

Comment: Thank you for typing.... but that does not make much sense because the error only occurs in console mode. It just works fine in server mode (i.e. `rails s` and paste the link in browser)